# Javascript gives error in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a js function which is called onchange of a drop-down.
It works in FF, IE6 and 7 and Safari.
In IE8 however the function breaks at the following line.

```
document.getElementById("shipModeId_1").options[document.getElementById("shipModeId_1").options.length]
  = Option(ship_modeId,selcted);
```

It says Object doesn't support this property or method.
Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks,

Sarego

Comment: Please add some surrounding code. What is `ship_modeId`, `selcted`, and `Option`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `new` operator. Also you probably want to pass in the same value for the `text` and the `value` arguments, with `selected` following that. The two-argument form of the `Option` constructor takes `text` and `value`, not `selected`.

```
new Option(ship_modeId, ship_modeId, selected)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a `<select>`, I don't think you need "options".

```
document.getElementById("shipModeId_1")[document.getElementById("shipModeId_1").length]  = new Option(ship_modeId,selcted);
```

You also missed "new" in generating the new option.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
var drpDown = document.getElementById("shipModeId_1");
drpDown.options[drpDown.options.length] = new Option(ship_modeId,selcted);
```